# Swift: How to set UIScrollView contentSize height to height of contents?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView. Right now I am just setting it to double the height of the screen (frame in this case is just `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`):

```
class VenueDetailView: UIScrollView {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("Storyboard makes me sad.") }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height*2) <----------------

    backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  }


  func addBannerImage(imageUrl: NSURL) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 300))

    // TODO: Make this asynchronous
    // Nice to have: cache the image
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl) {
      imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }

    addSubview(imageView)
  }
}
```

However, I just want it to be the size of all the contents inside it. How would I do this? Does this mean I have to set the `contentSize` after I add all the subviews?

Comment: the problem with the scroll view is, you shouldn't  really make the scroll view size equals to content size!!! If you do so, scroll view will not scroll!!! Content size should be bigger than scroll view size

Comment: well i expect my content to be really long, so setting content size to 2x the height of the screen makes it scrollable. however, i want the content size to be whatever the total height of the subviews is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this mean I have to set the contentSize after I add all the subviews?

Basically yes. Your goal should be to make the scroll view small and the content size big. That is what makes a scroll view scrollable: its `contentSize` is bigger than its own bounds size. So, set the scroll view itself to have a `frame` that is the same as the `bounds` of its superview, but then set its `contentSize` to embrace all its subviews.

Comment: how would i find the total height of all the subviews of a uiscrollview?

Comment: Here, from my book, is an example of me doing that: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p360scrollViewInCode/ch20p570scrollViewInCode/ViewController.swift In that example, the scroll view is created in code and so are all its contents, so I learn the height of the contents by watching the positions at which I put them; but the same thing is possible entirely in the storyboard editor, and later examples illustrate that.

Comment: so you store height as a var and every time you add a subview you increment it and in the end you set the scroll view's height to that var?

Comment: Basically yes! But keep in mind, the top is 0, obviously, so all you really need to know is the bottom of the bottom-most subview.

Comment: why would that be? wouldn't you want the content size = total of all the subviews? (+10 for padding as i see you've done in the example)

Comment: Think about the bottom-most view. It has a `frame`. That means it has an `origin.y` (its top) and a `size.height`. The sum is the `y` value of its bottom. But it is, _ex hypoethesi_, the bottom-most view. So that sum, the `y` value of the bottom of the bottom-most view, is the height of the `contentSize` (you could add a little more as bottom padding if you like).

Comment: You might want to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html The online version is in Objective-C, not Swift (the current version is in Swift), but you will understand the concepts nevertheless.

Comment: yeh i get what you mean. basically the y of the last one is the total height of the ones above it. thanks!

Comment: I just want to say that this is one of the most concise answers I've seen on the key parameters of UIScrollView.