# how to set scrollview content size in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swift3, cgsize

After updated Xcode8 not able to set `contentSize` for `ScrollView`. I can't able to use `CGSizeMake`.
Can anyone help me?

I have tried

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 700)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From Swift 3 `CGSizeMake` is not available use `CGSize` init instead.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 700)
```

Check the Apple Documentation on [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/) as of from Swift 3 they have made a lot of changes.

Comment: Thanks Buddy it works

Comment: Welcome mate :)